# Temperature is black after thresholding

Tags: opencv, heatmap, detection, dlib, image-thresholding

I want to show the temperature based on the density.

Following are the function that Im using,

```
def add_heat(heatmap, bbox_list):
    for i in range(len(bbox_list)):
        rect = trackers[i].get_position()

        heatmap[int(rect.left()):int(rect.top()), int(rect.right()):int(rect.bottom())] += 1
    return heatmap

def apply_threshold(heatmap, threshold):
    # Zero out pixels below the threshold
    heatmap[heatmap <= threshold] = 0
    # Return thresholded map

    cv2.imwrite("heatmap.png",heatmap)
    return heatmap
```

1. `add_heat` function will loop through the trackers and will tweak the heatmap only on those specific areas for the thresholding
2. apply_threshold will convert all pixels to zero if it is below certain threshold.

Im calling it as follows,

```
heat = np.zeros_like(frame[:, :, 0]).astype(np.float)
heat = add_heat(heat,trackers)
heat = apply_threshold(heat, 80)
heatmap = np.clip(heat, 0, 255)
```

trackers contains all the tracked coordinates. however when i try to show the final result, it is still black. May i know what am i missing?

Comment: Please provide a proper Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example. Where/how do you load the image? What image? What modules are you importing?

Comment: Your question sounds interesting but unclear. Please add more details as suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your problem lies in here:

```
heatmap[int(rect.left()):int(rect.top()), int(rect.right()):int(rect.bottom())] += 1
return heatmap
```

Assuming you want to use the heatmap with something like skimage, you should probably do it like this:

```
heatmap[top_row:bottom_row, leftmost_column:rightmost_column]
```

which in your code will look like this:

```
heatmap[int(rect.bottom()):int(rect.top()), int(rect.left()):int(rect.right())] += 1
return heatmap
```

You may want to read a little more about numpy arrays.
I was able to tell what is happening as I saw where this question [originated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077405/how-do-i-generate-a-heat-map-of-a-detected-object-based-on-its-position-using-op).